# Bootstrap modals not correctly hiding

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

First and foremost, the code is a mess because I had gotten some outside help from a person who did not take his coding seriously, right now I need to meet a deadline and am focusing on functionality, so I apologize beforehand, I'll get to cleaning it up in time.

We are creating a simple shopping page that includes PHP, bootstrap. We store the product information the in a mysqli database. We have multiple modals for each item where you can choose the size, and then add them to the cart.

The problem is that while the bootstrap modals cannot be seen, they are still "clickable" as if they were active when they are not. This does not apply to the cart modal, at least as far as I can tell.

I tried to fix this by changing the z index of the class of modals, however, that did not work.

the html (and PHP):

```html
 <section class="products">
    <?php
    $db = new Database();
    $db->connect();
    $db->select('tbl_items','productid,Product_Name,Product_Price,Product_Quantity,Category,Product_Picture',NULL,'Category!="Beverage" and Product_Quantity > 0','productid ASC'); // Table name, Column Names, JOIN, WHERE conditions, ORDER BY conditions
    $res = $db->getResult();
    $rows = array();
    foreach ($res as $row) 
    {?>
    <div class="product-card">
        <form method="post" class="product-form card-form">
            <div class="product-image">
                <?php echo '<img class="gallery-pic responsive" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Product_Picture'] ).'"/>';?>
            </div>

            <div class="product-info-container">
                <div class="product-info">
                    <h3 id="prod-name" class="prod-info"><?php echo $row['Product_Name']; ?><h3>
                </div>

                <div class="product-info">
                    <span class="prod-info">
                        <h4>R<?php echo $row['Product_Price']; ?></h4>
                    </span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="product-info add-btn-container">
                <div class="customn-btn btn-lg btn-block add-cart-btn" title="Add to FOGo"
                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product<?php echo $row['productid'];?>modal"
                    onclick="resetSize()">
                    Add to cart<i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I assign the product ID to the id of the modal to so that it can be referenced in the add to cart button above

Continue in the loop:

```html
        <div class="modal fade product-modal" id="product<?php echo $row['productid'];?>modal"
        role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header color-gradient">
                    <button type="button" title="Close Plate" class="close"
                        data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 id="item-title" class="modal-title"><?php echo $row['Product_Name'];?></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="display-pic-container">
                    <?php echo '<img class=" responsive" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Product_Picture'] ).'"/>';?>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="size-lbl" for="size">Size</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="size" onchange="changeSize(event)">
                            <option value="Small">Small</option>
                            <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                            <option value="Large">Large</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" title="Close Plate"
                        class="close-btn btn-lg btn-block cart-btn" id="close_cart"
                        data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Close</button>

                    <span onclick="addToCart(<?php echo $row['productid'];?>, event )" 
                        title="Add to cart" class="btn-lg btn-block cart-btn check-out-btn"><i
                            class="fa fa-credit-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Add to cart</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
</section>
```

Comment: Are you using `<!-- -->` HTML comment blocks inside PHP? And also "read products from db" isn't a comment in this snippet. Please copy & paste your _actual_ codebase so we can help you :-)

Comment: You are violating the basic rule that IDs must be unique within an HTML document, in multiple places there. And in the places where you tried to avoid that, the syntax isn’t correct - `<div class="modal fade product-modal" id="product<?php echo $row['productid'];?>\`modal role="dialog">` - you are not properly closing the value of that ID attribute there.

Comment: @Reece I just put the comments in this question for the answerers' sake because I thought it was easier to understand though I will edit it to take it out

Comment: @04FS Apologies that was a typo since stack overflow was hitting me with the code not formatted correctly error I'll edit it here but in the code, it is closed properly, will edit it now, sorry

Comment: Are you sure you are including the proper bootstrap css? because you are outputting the HTML code of the modals multiple times directly in your page, if your JS automatically fires them and you are missing the css of bootstrap then i guess you are going to have some weird situations. Please double-check you are including proper JS and CSS from bootstrap